# TextInputLayout disable animation

Tags: android

I am using the TextInputLayout to implement the floating label pattern. However, when I set the text programmatically on the EditText, I still get the animation of the label moving from the control to the label - the same as if the user had clicked it.

I don't want this animation though if I set it programmatically, is this possible? Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And in the onResume I do:

```
    TextInputLayout root = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
    EditText et = (EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et.setText("Actual text");
    root.setHint("Hint");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found an (unwieldy) way to do that. Looking into the source code of the `TextInputLayout`, I've discovered that the only occasion when the class doesn't update it's hint with animation is when the `EditText` is added to it. The only obstacle is that you can only add it once to the layout, once it is there, it will permanently be tied to it, and there's no way to remove it.

So here's the solution:

1. Create a `TextInputLayout` **without the `EditText`**. Programmatically or via XML inflation - doesn't matter, but it has to be empty.
2. Create the `EditText` and set its text to whatever you need.
3. Add the `EditText` to the `TextInputLayout`.

Here's an example:

```
TextInputLayout hintView = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.hint_view);
hintView.setHint(R.string.hint);

EditText fieldView = new EditText(hintView.getContext());
fieldView.setText(value);

hintView.addView(fieldView);
```

Unfortunately, if you want to set the text to something else without the animation, you will have to repeat all these steps, except for the creation of a new `EditText` (the last one can be reused). I hope Google can fix this, because it is really inconvenient, but for now that's what we have.

**Update:** this is, thankfully, fixed in the design library 23.0.0, so just update to that version, and you won't have to do all this crazy stuff.

Comment: Great job! I needed exactly the same thing and was struggling with this. It's a pity that ```TextInputLayout``` is still a bit buggy. It has a lot of these little issues

Comment: @Malcolm Could you please tell me where you found source code for TextInputLayout?

Comment: @VitalyZinchenko I think I just opened it in Android Studio. Maybe it did some decompilation, I don't remember exactly right now.

Answer (score 45):

As of v23 of the support libs, a `setHintAnimationEnabled` [method has been added](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179776#c10). Here are [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHintAnimationEnabled(boolean)). So you can set [this new attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:hintAnimationEnabled) to `false` in the XML and then programmatically set it to `true` after you've finished populating the editText. OR simply handle it all programmatically, as needed.

So in your example, that would become something like:

```
TextInputLayout root = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
root.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);
root.setHint("Hint");

EditText et = (EditText)root.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
et.setText("Actual text");

// later...
root.setHintAnimationEnabled(true);
```

Of course, be sure to open your Android SDK Manager and update your *Android Support Library* to rev. 23 and *Android Support Repository* to rev. 17 first and then add that to build.gradle via:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

> Note that as the Design library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries, those will be included automatically when you add the Design library dependency.

Comment: Side note: here's a report of [everything that changed from v22.2.1 to v23](https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes.html). You can click on "[TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes/android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.html)" on the side navigation and see these methods added to the class.

Comment: shouldn't it be compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'

Comment: One note, the animation need to be turned off before we set the text/hint. Having the sequence wrong would not turn off the animation.

Answer (score 6):

```
Put this attribute app:hintEnabled="false" here:

 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintEnabled="false">
```

It works for me

Answer (score 5):

You can disable it by using

```
app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
```

Answer (score 3):

I will give you simple code and you don't have to make all programmatically just add xlm attribute and that's all.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_field_activity_login"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_holo_light_gray"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/color_holo_light_gray"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_drawable" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: how do I use this using themes if I have plenty of TIL's already defined?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small method to run after loading the view hierarchy that disables animation on initial display but enables it after wards. Add this to your Base Activity/Fragment/View and it will solve it issue.

```
private void setTextInputLayoutAnimation(View view) {
        if (view instanceof TextInputLayout) {
            TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) view;
            til.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);
            til.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    til.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    til.setHintAnimationEnabled(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return;
        }

        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
            for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = group.getChildAt(i);
                setTextInputLayoutAnimation(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I check out ideas about support library v23 - it's does not work yet :( Programmatically inserting of EditText is unusable if you wish to use databinding labrary

In result of research I found solution without full disabling of animation:

#### layout.xml

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:id="@+id/text_til"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/product_title_placeholder">
     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/text_tiet"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@={bindingText}"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

#### Activity.java

```java
final TextInputLayout textLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_til);
if(binding.getText() != null) {
   // disable animation
   textLayout.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);
   final TextInputEditText editText = (TextInputEditText) titleLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_tiet);
   editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
           // enable animation after layout inflated
           textLayout.setHintAnimationEnabled(true);
           editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(null);
       }
   });
}
// manage focus for new binding object
((View)textLayout .getParent()).setFocusableInTouchMode(binding.getText() == null);
```

It's looks not prettily, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the hint value the to the **TextInputEditText** instead of  **TextInputLayout**  Then add **app:hintEnabled="false"** to the **TextInputLayout**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tlFullName"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etFullName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/fullName"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```